# How postgresql manage columns

Tags: database, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I want to know the way how postgresql manage columns of table.

Say for e.g

I have created one table that contains 2 fields, so how postgresql manage these columns, table?  In how many tables postgresql create entry for a single column ?

I would like to know the structure how the postgresql manage table and it's fields.

I only about **pg_attribute** table.

It would be good if anyone can share useful links.

Any help would be really appriciated.

Comment: theres a lot of information about the `pg_catalog` schema in the documentation

Comment: please read http://stackoverflow.com/a/43050467/5315974

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tables (and indexes) are organized in 8KB blocks in files in the data directory.

The column definitions are *only* in `pg_attribute`.

A table row with all its columns is stored together in one table block, and a table block can contain several such rows. In other words, PostgreSQL uses the traditional *row oriented* storage model.

Details can be read in [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/storage-page-layout.html).

**Note:** Don't use PostgreSQL 9.1 any more.